# Using htmlagility xpath's to find webdriver elements

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium, html-agility-pack, webdriver

I'm using htmlagility pack to locate elements in large loops through tables because its much faster than using the native methods provided through webdriver.

After locating a specific element through the looping I'm getting its xpath, then feeding that to webdriver to return an element.

However I'm getting an exception;

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: FindElementByXPath.

```
//html[1]//body[1]//mpns:multipage[1]//mpns:pageview[1]//table[1]//

[Test]
[Browser(BrowserType.IE)]
public void Simple_HtmlAgility_Xpath()
{
    Browser.GoTo("http://test/");
    Browser.Login().Login_Admin();

    using (Browser.SwitchToFrame("main"))
    {
        var html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        html.LoadHtml(Browser.PageSource);
        var node = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@id='testtable']");
        var xpath = node.XPath.Replace("/", "//");
        Log.Debug(xpath);
        var element = Browser.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath));
        Log.Debug(element.Text);
    }
}
```

an example of the page;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <title>Welcome</title>        
    </HEAD>
    <body>
        <?XML:NAMESPACE PREFIX="MPNS" /><?IMPORT NAMESPACE="MPNS" IMPLEMENTATION="/webctrl_client/1_0/multipage.htc" />
      <MPNS:MultiPage id="test1">
       <MPNS:PageView>        
        <table width="100%" id="testtable">
            <tr>
                <td>TEST</td>
            </tr>
        </table>                            
       </MPNS:PageView>
      </MPNS:MultiPage>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You need to provide a small example of the XML (HTML) on which you get this exception. Without it one can only guess about the cause of the error.

Comment: Hmm seems changing everything into double slashes helps, maybe problem is with mpns namespace

Comment: I think you could refactor your page in a more standar compat mode declaring `MPNS` prefix as `xmlns:MPNS="SOME_URI"` and ussing CSS rule `MPNS\:MultiPage, MPNS\:MultiPage {-ms-behavior: url(/webctrl_client/1_0/multipage.htc)}`. IE has some special SGML "namespaces" handling...

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Xpath cannot reference `mpns` namespace and you need to define it in your XPath query. Please see [this](http://bobcat.webappcabaret.net/javachina/faq/xpath_01.htm#xpath_Q15) for some details